# Replacing files in subdirectories if they have the same name that files in a specific folder - Python

Tags: python

I have PDF files in a specific folder (C:\PDF) => they are my right files
and I would like to find and replace elsewhere in a Folder and its subfolders (C:\Folders...) all the files with the same names among many PDF files

I use this PowerShell command to do exactly what I want :

```
replace "C:\PDF\*.pdf" "C:\Folders" /s
```

but it is more convenient for me to do that in Python (I already have Python scripts to run and I want to do everything in one single script)

Do you have any idea to do it in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to run the command from python.
See the subprocess.run [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

Disclaimer I don't have a windows machine so this hasn't been tested.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["replace", "C:\PDF\*.pdf", "C:\Folders", "/s"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, before I try it, we don't have to precise to Python what language we want to run (i.e. PowerShell) ?

Comment: No, because we *aren't using a language* here; we're just giving a command to the operating system to run that program.

Comment: It works very well !!! I just had to put a "r" before the path, Thank you fanta fles